# Are there alternatives for proof of work?

Tags: security, doublespend, proof-of-work, proof-of-stake, consensus

Bitcoin uses proof of work to secure the network, Ripple uses a global consensus system and PPCoin uses proof of stake.

Are there any known alternatives to the above methods?

Comment: in the ppc paper they talk about a 'proof of excellence' where all peers compete to solve a game. It is basically proof of work, buta better algorithm could score higher.

Comment: @David Perry. This is a subtly different question than what you've suggested as a duplicate. This person is asking if there exist alternative distributed synchronization algorithms. The other question asks if the proof-of-work system can prove secondarily-useful work. There is a clear difference.

Comment: @Rooke fair enough, I'll re-open it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to set up proof-of-work systems so it would be even more useful?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/331/is-there-a-way-to-set-up-proof-of-work-systems-so-it-would-be-even-more-useful)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another alternative is [proof of burn](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Proof_of_burn).

Answer (score 6):

A really quick answer is this: The proof of work system is a solution to the distributed synchronization issue; in another guise it is called the [Byzantine Generals' Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byzantine_fault_tolerance). Thus, any solution to this problem is an acceptable alternative, however the proof-of-work solution is particularly suited to distributed systems.

You can read Satoshi Nakamoto's discussion of this [here](http://www.mail-archive.com/cryptography@metzdowd.com/msg09997.html).

Answer (score 2):

I have been researching on blockchain for sometime now and some of them I found are a mix of some existing and some proposed.

1. Proof-of-Stake
2. Proof-of-Burn
3. Proof-of-Capacity
4. Proof-of-Activity
5. Proof-of-Checkpoint

Source: https://bytecoin.org/blog/proof-of-activity-proof-of-burn-proof-of-capacity/

Comment: Link is dead. https://web.archive.org/web/20160304055454/https://bytecoin.org/blog/proof-of-activity-proof-of-burn-proof-of-capacity/