# Meta-Mining: Can mining exist in abstract states?

Tags: bitcoin-core, mining-pools, mining-theory

Has anyone here explored or pondered possibilities for meta-mining?

Theoretically, you could have miners work on any computational problem, and then have rewards handed out proportionally as part of a programmable smart-contract, based upon how the contribution to this mass-calculation is progressing.

This form of mining could itself be tied to side-chains and the actual blockchain, but executed through applications which make mining more agile and customizable to a specific computational or explorational need.

Are these "meta-mining" practices possible?

Comment: You might need to suggest some possible uses of this. The suggestion for using other systems for proof of work comes up a lot, but there's very little it would actually be applicable for. Needs to have progress but probably not a huge state, not have secret contents, and no reason for people to withhold the results.

Comment: Running an electrical grid on a mining system, for example, could be one usage.

Comment: @RyanStrauss I'm confused. What part of the electrical grid would the miners run? Would they control how power is switched?

Comment: This question also seems very similar to http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/331/is-there-a-way-to-set-up-proof-of-work-systems-so-they-would-be-even-more-useful

Comment: @Bitcoin correction: Mining must NOT have progress.

Comment: @Jannes The whole question is sort of confused really. For proof of work you certainly don't want measurable progress, but they're not quite talking about that I didn't think. Might need to get some clarification on uses.

Comment: @Bitcoin yeah, the question does not make a single sense. You might be right. But then maybe it could just have (huge) state and secret contents as well. Better just wait for clarification, I guess.