# Who benefits from mining?

Tags: mining-theory

After reading many articles, I didn't find an answer to the following.

> "Miners use special software to solve math problems"

Okay, but for whom? Are there organizations or people that need those math problems to be solved?

Comment: Everyone who uses Bitcoins needs those math problems solved because it's the solution of those problems that secures the blockchain against double spend attacks.

Comment: related: [Is there a way to set up proof-of-work systems so they would be even more useful?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/331/5406)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not a math problem. Its just search for partial collision in function called sha256.

Sha256 is a famous type of puzzle.

During the writing of this post, a block  397108 was mined.

The solution looks like this:
00000000000000000497b28e9c38673ef8fd2fed317d6eca8a579350b1cba0a6

Notice the zeroes on the beginning. The more zeroes the harder is to find a solution.

The only reason is to waste power to prevent creation of funds from thin air (prevent print too much money) and to confirm payments.

Comment: Actually the problem is not finding a collision. The correct terminology is a [preimage attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preimage_attack), where you are given a target hash value (000...000) and want to find an input that hashes to it.