# Why does mining / validation of new blocks have to be complicated / time consuming?

Tags: blockchain, mining-theory

Why does mining / validation of new blocks have to be complicated / time consuming ?
Why it can't be as simple as just find a hash for a text?
Is it just to control / limit the amount of new crypto volumes coming in ? If this is the case, isn't it an energy consumption issue ? Aren't there any other solutions ?

Sorry for asking too many questions. I am just a bit confused.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do we need Proof of Work in bitcoin?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/51286/why-do-we-need-proof-of-work-in-bitcoin)

Answer (score 0):

If mining was simple I could find a hundred million blocks in the next five seconds.

Would that be helpful? What would we do with all those blocks?

Thinking about these questions should help you answer yours.